# Rxjs concatMap return type to Observable<boolean>

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs

1. I have one service which is returning promise
2. Other is posting data and returning saved data
3. After successfully save, return true

So return type of method should be `Observable<boolean>` and not `Observable<any>`, here is the code

```
// I want it's return type to be Observable<boolean>
saveUser(record: any): Observable<any> {
      return from(this.getUserById(1))
        .pipe(concatMap((data: any) => {
           // Some other code....
           return this.httpClient.post(`${this.API_URL}/users`, record)
            .pipe(
              map((result: any) => { 
                console.log(result);
                return true; 
              }), 
              catchError(error => this.handleError(error))
            )
        }));
}
```

I want, it's return type to be `Observable<boolean>` but when I change to Observable, immediately start getting error.

See the workin sample code on [StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-4ucmuz?file=src/app/app.component.html)

> Note: I cannot change any other methods except `saveUser(record:
>   any)`!

Answer (score 1):

The problem is with your `catchError` function.

If you throw, there is no return type, function doesn't return.

You can handle error and return an observable:

```
private handleError(error: Response | any): Observable<boolean> {
  return of(false);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This is the proper way of handling your methods:

First and foremost, as mentioned on the [documentation](https://rxjs-dev.firebaseapp.com/api/index/function/throwError), `throwError` returns `Observable<never>`. In fact, there is not need to type your parameter as a union type of `Response` or `any`. This is how you should define your handleError method (instead of setting the return type as `any`):

```
private handleError(error: Response): Observable<never> {
  return throwError(error);
}
```

And then, on your `saveUser` method, it can possible return an observable of type `boolean`, or `never`. Therefore, the return type should be `Observable<boolean | never>`

```
saveUser(record: any): Observable<boolean | never> {
  return from(this.getUserById(1))
    .pipe(concatMap((data: any) => {
        return this.httpClient.post(`${this.API_URL}/users`, record)
        .pipe(
          map((result: any) => { 
            console.log(result);
            return true; 
          }), 
          catchError(error => this.handleError(error))
        )
    }));
}
```

Here is the [working demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-qrdptp?file=src/app/app.component.ts), without any TypeScript errors.

Answer (score 0):

Am I right in saying that this is only a linting problem?

You say you can **only** change saveUser, so I'm going to assume you can't change handleError to return `Observable<boolean>` to suit your purposes.

Instead, you can coerce typescript into behaving by re-declaring typed versions of the other functions you're calling:

```
saveUser(record: any): Observable<boolean> {
  const _catchError: OperatorFunction<any, boolean> = catchError(error => this.handleError(error));
  return from(this.getUserById(1))
    .pipe(concatMap((data: any) => {
        return this.httpClient.post(`${this.API_URL}/users`, record)
        .pipe(
          map((result: any): boolean => { 
            console.log(result);
            return true; 
          }), 
          _catchError
        )
    }));
}
```

Edit: working demo: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-s4zw4q